# Error processing SQL:0 PhoneGap SQL

Tags: javascript, sql, html, cordova

Im trying out and copied code from here:
http://luthfihariz.wordpress.com/2011/10/23/android-sqlite-phonegap-jquerymobile/
To succeed with a sample I'm working on just to learn this.
I have a link to my complete index.html on pastebin.

Please, correct me and also help me finding this errror.

[Link to Pastebin here](http://pastebin.com/L63Np7E4)

Comment: Does your error indicate which line is throwing that error? Could you also try moving the opendatabase call into the onDeviceReady method?

Comment: I get an alert which says at first "success!" and then I press OK, after that another one pops up. That one says "Error processing SQL: 0".

Comment: I gave your code a closer look and have a few ideas, but none of them I can definitively say are the root cause. I think the best thing you can do for now  is add some more logging to determine which line is causing you to enter your errorCB function. Once you can at least understand how it got to your error function we can more accurately debug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn't have a lot of time, and it's soon xmas :)  But.. :)   I did write you a working example with your code as a starter.

Using Cordova version 2.2.0
Using PhoneGap to compile
I did test it on an android device
I did change some things here and there, but I used the code frome [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html) as a reference.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

var db = "";

function populateDB(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS SoccerPlayer');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SoccerPlayer (Name TEXT NOT NULL, Club TEXT NOT NULL)');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO SoccerPlayer(Name,Club) VALUES ("Alexandre Pato", "AC Milan")');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO SoccerPlayer(Name,Club) VALUES ("Van Persie", "Arsenal")');
}

function queryDB(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM SoccerPlayer', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
}


function querySuccess(tx,result){
        var playerlist = document.getElementById("SoccerPlayerList");
        var players = "";
        alert("The show is on");
        var len = result.rows.length;
        for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
            alert(result.rows.item(i).Name + result.rows.item(i).Club);
            players = players + '<li><a href="#"><p class="record">'+result.rows.item(i).Name+'</p><p class="small">Club '+result.rows.item(i).Club+'</p></a></li>';
        }   

        playerlist.innerHTML = players;
        $("#SoccerPlayerList").listview("refresh");
}


function errorCB(err) {
    alert("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
}


function successCB() {
    db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);
}


function onDeviceReady() {
    db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000);
    db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, merry christmas! Lifesaver! :D