# PhoneGap error process SQL : 0

Tags: javascript, cordova

trying to solve this problem since week even when I tried to this solution :

[Error processing SQL:0 PhoneGap SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13974648/error-processing-sql0-phonegap-sql)

Error Message :
the SQLTransactionCallback was null or threw an exception.

code :

```
function star(tx){
var sql = "INSERT INTO xTable (id, qid, title, answer, isman) VALUES (?,?,?,?,0)";
tx.executeSql(sql,[arr[0],arr[1],arr[2],arr[3]],done);
}

function done (tx,results){
alert (results.rows.length);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function star(tx){
var sql = "INSERT INTO xTable (id, qid, title, answer, isman) VALUES (?,?,?,?,0)";
tx.executeSql(sql,[arr[0],arr[1],arr[2],arr[3]],done,onerror);
}

function done (tx,results){
alert (results.rows.length);
}

function onerror(error){
console.log(error);
}
```

try this